# Google Fonts URL giving 404

Tags: google-fonts

In my crawl (SEO Audit) of the website, I am seeing https://fonts.googleapis.com/css this URL mentioned in the header of each page and when you click it gives 404 because you need to mention font family like https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tangerine. 
After discussing with the tech team, they mentioned that it's fine because - "The 404 fonts URL is not an issue since it has the `DNS-prefetch` parameter which is simply telling the browser to load anything from the `fonts.googleapis.com`"

This is the complete code:

```
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com" rel=dns-prefetch />
```

I am wondering if this correct and is not an issue?

Comment: The mentioned code seems to be missing.

Comment: Its showing when I edit but after posting it disappears, but here is the code:    
 <link href="//fonts.googleapis.com" rel=dns-prefetch />